# Workflow to animate character rig with an already animated model

Tags: unity, animation, blender, asset-workflow

How should I go about animating character rigs (walking, running, ducking, ...) with already animated assets? Do I load the animated asset into the project file of my character rig or do I attach the animated asset to the rig in the engine?

I am using Blender for the models and Unity3D as the engine.